# check another validation rules after validating blank field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to validate another ready made bad words filter after validating first rules (blank fields). I have all codes in ready made, someone please help me to add this second validation in my page.

This is my jquery codes where I need to include the 2nd validation.

```
$(function() {
$("#review").focus(function() {
    $("#comments").removeClass('hide')
});
$("#sky-form").validate({
    rules: {
        digits: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        },
        name: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        digits: {
            required: 'Please enter a valid amount of Money'
        },
        name: {
            required: 'Please enter your username',
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(g) {
        $(g).ajaxSubmit({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#sky-form button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true)
            },
            success: function() {success funtion goes here}
```

This is the 2nd validation codes that I need to include on top. Mainly I need this function - bwords=badwords(textbox_val); - It will verify bad word's after blank fields is okay.

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Message()
    {

    var textbox_val=document.form.textbox.value;
    if(textbox_val=="")
    {
    alert("Please enter a message");
    return false;
    }

    bwords=badwords(textbox_val);
    if(bwords>0)
    {
    alert("Your message contains inappropriate words. Please clean up your message.");
    document.form.textbox.focus();
    return false;
    }

    }
    </script>
```

Those both function is working but I just need to include both validation like 2nd one in the top first script.

Sorry for my bad Enlgish.

Comment: Can anybody help me please? if anyone have any issues on understand my problem then please post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new rule in your code. I called this rule badWords and for me the
bad word is BAD so when you try to type BAD in the name field you  will get the 
validation error message.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("badWords", function(value, element) {
  if (value.trim().length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (value == 'BAD') {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}, "BAD WORD");
$(function () {
  $("#sky-form").validate({
    rules: {
      digits: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
      },
      name: {
        required: true,
        badWords: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      digits: {
        required: 'Please enter a valid amount of Money'
      },
      name: {
        required: 'Please enter your username',
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<form id="sky-form">
    <label for="ele1">Digits:</label>
    <input type="text" id="ele1" name="digits"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="ele2">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="ele2" name="name"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much gaemaf sir for your kind response but I'm failed to give you the understanding what exactly I need, if you want then I can give you both ready made files so you can take a look on first one that I need to include in second one. is it possible to send you files?

Comment: Sorry but in Italy is midnight and I need to sleep. See soon and thanks so much